# Can I use the projection operator to prove this conclusion?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let A,B be closed subspaces of a Banach space $V$ such that $V = A \bigoplus B$. Prove that for any $v\in V$, $v = v_1+v_2$, there exists a constant C such that $C\|v_1 + v_2\|\leq\|v\|$.

I knew we can define another norm in $V$ like $\|v\| = \|v_1\| + \|v_2\|$, then it's easy to prove this norm is equivalent to the original one.  I was wondering whether I can use the projection operator: $P: V \rightarrow A$, which must be an opening map.

Comment: The mapping $A\oplus B\ni (v_1,v_2)\mapsto v_1+v_2\in V$ is a bounded bijection. By the Banach theorem this operator has a bounded inverse. That implies the  desired inequality.